# PostgreSQL 12.2 with Sequelize 6.3 - UPSERT a array of data and want ON CONFLIT DO UPDATE to merge current existing JSONB and EXCLUDED JSONB

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm currently using this query to insert or update my array of data when retrieving my list :

```js
    try {
      const query = `INSERT INTO "Tables" ("id","tomerge","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ${UpsertData
        .map((_) => '(?)')
        .join(
          ',',
        )} ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "tomerge"= "Tables"."tomerge" || excluded."tomerge", "updatedAt"=excluded."updatedAt";`;

      return await sequelize.query(query, {
        replacements: UpsertData,
        type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new DatabaseError(error);
    }
```

With my upsertData format :

```js
[{
  id: uuid,
  tomerge: { // JSON B
             [id]: score,
           },
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
},
{
  ...
}]
```

This code is currently working but I want the line

```js
"tomerge"= "Tables"."tomerge" || excluded."tomerge"
```

to MERGE my current json B with the new json B or updating the already existing line inside it

I'm searching on this case but I don't find anything that really work for jsonB, am I missing some case ?